# Find the image of spherical surface x^2+y^2+z^2=1 under the composite transformation

Tags: spherical-geometry, geometric-transformation

[image]

\begin{array}{l}
( 5-1) \ From\ the\ question,\ the\ normal\ vector\ of\ plane\ x+y+z=0,\ \vec{u} =( 1,1,1)^{T}\\
According\ to\ Householder\ Transformation,\ g=I-2\vec{u}\vec{u} =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} -\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
2\\
2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -2 & -2\\
-2 & -1 & -2\\
-2 & -2 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{array}

For (5-2), I don't understand what the image is. And how to relate the composition transformation with the spherical surface? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The _image_ of a set $S$ under a function $f$ is just $f(S)=\{f(x):x\in S\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have been warned by obtaining the unity matrix for the matrix of a symmetry...

Your error comes from the fact that Householder formula $I-2NN^T$ is valid for a *unit(arized)* vector $N$. So take $N=(1,1,1)/\sqrt{3}$ instead of $N=(1,1,1)$.

Now, what can you expect for the final result ?

Inspection of the diagonal blocks of the first matrix make it an "elongator" by factor $k$ in the $x$ direction, and a "rotator" around this same $x$ direction. Therefore, the image of the unit sphere is an ellipsoid. with semi-axes $k,1,1$. Composition by a symmetry will not change the general shape (still an ellipsoid with the same semi-axes).

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I seem to understand now. So, is it true that the result of inputting the parameter equation of the unit sphere into the composite transformation is the parameter equation of an ellipsoid? Is that right?

Comment: That's right...